# KVM: How is CPU usage related to Ping?

Tags: ubuntu, ping, cpu-usage, linux-kvm

I was running some tests pinging from Ubuntu KVM guest to Ubuntu KVM guest and I noticed something interesting that I'm trying to understand. I increased CPU usage by starting up additional guests that were using 99% of their own CPU.

What I started to notice was that a low CPU load gave worse ping results than a medium CPU load. Then, once the CPU load is increased to high, the ping results get worse again. Why is this the case? Is there something going on behind the scenes that improves ping latency when the CPU load is not too low and not too high?

edit: Just to clarify what I mean by "worse": Low CPU load: 0.5ms ping | medium CPU load: 0.05-0.1ms ping | high CPU load: 0.4-0.6ms ping

edit: Again, I'm trying to mainly understand why a medium CPU load would result in a better ping latency than a low CPU load.

Comment: I'd recommend posting some figures if you want to get a rreasonable answer. We have no idea what a "worse ping result" ist and we also don't know the precision of your ping result times (resolution varies).

Comment: added some figures for a reasonable answer. Main question is what could be some possible causes for a medium CPU load leading to shorter average ping round trip time than a low CPU load.

Comment: These are very low values from a networking and scheduling perspective while they are high values from a CPU throttling perspective, given how trivial the task of a ping actually is. Of course, we still don't know how many CPU cores / threads you have, how many CPU consuming guests you start and how they burn CPU cycles. Keep in mind that your scenario involves virtual networking. I believe you see a combination of network and task scheduling effects.

Comment: Most likely this is KVMs doing. first understand that most hypervisors never directly associate a virtual core with a physical one, instead running by timeslicing across all of their cores as needed by the aggregate load of the guests. but when the guest is configured for multiple cores for instance, the host has to be able to allocated multiple physical cores for use by the guest. If a guest is mostly idle, the other guests will get precedence for cpu access, and when teh guest becomes un-idle, the host must scramble to synchronize a time-slice across enough cores. VMWare calls this CPUReady.

Comment: Cont. In the case of the medium use system, the host is already scheduling slices across sufficient cores for the guest, so there is no delay. It helps not to overbook cores on the host, but even then most hypervisors assign by `MHz/Time * SMP threads`, rather than mapping raw cores to virtual ones so that they can achieve overbooking if desired.

Comment: Ah I see. Ok this is extremely helpful and I appreciate the input. at first I thought the pattern I was seeing had more to do with the idea that at low CPU load, there is extra time spend getting the CPU going as compared to with medium load, the CPU is already running full speed. You've given me new insight. I didn't even think about how hypervisors deal with multi-cored guests since mine in this case are given a single vCPU each

Answer (score 1):

This has very little to do with "ping" per-se, and everything to do with the underlying system.

In order for Ping (or any Internet application) to work, it involves calls to the software [ and hardware ] Internet stack.   When the CPU gets busy it allocates less time and resources to servicing the stack, which pushes up latency.

Comment: That's my main question! I figured as CPU load went up, the ping latency would get worse. However, as I said, this isn't entirely the case. While ping latency was definitely worst with a high CPU, I don't understand why ping latency was better with a medium CPU load than a low CPU. By your idea above, shouldn't a medium CPU load result in a worse ping latency than a low CPU load?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things, including if process scheduler and current speed of the CPU - for example, when a laptop is on battery mode and only being lightly used, the system slows the clock speeds to save power.  If the system is unused, and the scheduler has not picked up a need it can react more sluggishly "because its sleepy"- similarly, a moderately used CPU may have a core not doing much which can be allocated to handling the IP stack.

Comment: Ah I see. I can see how the results I'm seeing could come from a large variety of sources... Is it possible that it may have something to do with a low load uses extra time to wake up the CPU (as opposed to the CPU already running full throttle with a medium load)..so that could cause the high latency with the lower load?